# Adding Numbers in a Cell and Multiplying Them by a Corresponding String in the Same Cell

Tags: excel, vba

First time using VBA in Excel. Trying to add up numbers in a cell and multiply them by a corresponding string (i.e. singles, cpls, grp/3...grp/12) that is next to them in the same cell. An example cell would be something like this: 7 singles, 8 cpls, 4 grp/3, 2 grp/5, 1 grp/8. This is to make my job slightly easier but I'm not sure what's wrong with my code so any help would be great!

```
Function SumNums(pWorkRng As Range) As Double
    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim xIndex As Long
    arr = Split(pWorkRng, ",")

    Dim j As Long
    j = 1
    
    Dim amounts(1 To 12) As String
    amounts(1) = "singles"
    amounts(2) = "cpls"
    amounts(3) = "grp/3"
    amounts(4) = "grp/4"
    amounts(5) = "grp/5"
    amounts(6) = "grp/6"
    amounts(7) = "grp/7"
    amounts(8) = "grp/8"
    amounts(9) = "grp/9"
    amounts(10) = "grp/10"
    amounts(11) = "grp/11"
    amounts(12) = "grp/12"

    For xIndex = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 1
        Do Until StrComp(amounts(j), arr(xIndex)) = 0
            j = j + 1
        Loop
        
        SumNums = SumNums + (VBA.Val(arr(xIndex)) * j)
        j = 1
    Next
End Function
```

Some code was taken from here: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3087-excel-sum-adding-numbers-in-a-single-cell.html

Comment: A string like "7 singles" can't be split on a comma because there is no comma. Use `arr = Split(pWorkRng, " ")` or simply `arr = Split(pWorkRng)` instead. Your question doesn't make clear where the original value comes from. If it's that you want to add the new cell value to the one it had before you must first capture the previous value. However, if the intention is to make your job easier the approach is wrong: Mixing numbers and text in the same cell is a recipe for a harder job. Consider using cell formatting if you can't provide two cells.

Answer (score 1):

The modification of your code offered below would extract a number from an entry like "7 singles" and multiply it with the multiplier implied by the text, e.g. "7 singles" or "7 pcs" or "7 Pieces" would return 7 whereas "7 pairs" or "7 dozen" would return 14 or 84 respectively. Perhaps this is what you had in mind. And perhaps the way I encoded my idea will guide you in making your own work.

```
Function SumNums(Cell As Range) As Double

    Dim Multi(1 To 12)  As String
    Dim CellVal         As String           ' Cell.Value
    Dim Sp()            As String           ' split of CellVal
    Dim i               As Integer          ' loop counter
    
    Multi(1) = "singles,pieces,pcs"
    Multi(2) = "cpls,pairs"
    Multi(3) = "grp/3"
    Multi(4) = "grp/4"
    Multi(5) = "grp/5"
    Multi(6) = "grp/6"
    Multi(7) = "grp/7"
    Multi(8) = "grp/8"
    Multi(9) = "grp/9"
    Multi(10) = "grp/10"
    Multi(11) = "grp/11"
    Multi(12) = "grp/12,dozens"

    ' remove accidental extra spaces
    CellVal = Replace(Trim(Cell.Value), "  ", " ")
    Sp = Split(CellVal)                     ' separate value & multiplier with a space!
    If UBound(Sp) Then                      ' skip if Cell holds no multiplier
        ' remove abbreviation point, like in "pcs." or "doz."
        If Right(Sp(1), 1) = "." Then Sp(1) = Trim(Replace(Sp(1), ".", ""))
        For i = UBound(Multi) To 2 Step -1  ' Multiplier = 1 by default
            If InStr(1, Multi(i), Sp(1), vbTextCompare) Then Exit For
        Next
        SumNums = Val(Sp(0)) * i
    Else
        SumNums = Val(CellVal)
    End If
End Function
```

The function is intended as UDF and can be called from the worksheet with a call like =SumNums(A1), where A1 holds a text like "7 singles".